# Installing android on htc touch 2

Tags: windows-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

It is possible to install Android OS on HTC Touch 2? And if it possible can you guys help me with a tutorial or something like this ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems from [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=852474) on XDA developers that there are people working on getting android to run on the HTC Touch2, but it doesn't look like its working yet.

It would be best for you to keep your eyes on that project, that seems like the best chance of you being able to run android on your phone.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, to do any OS modifications you will need a rooted device. In the commercial phones this root privilege is not available. Also, m not sure if the hardware supports Android OS.

If it supports then you will need the entire phone binary (or individual image files) which has to be flashed onto the device using fastboot.

Best of Luck with ur research on this...

Though seriously, I doubt that can be done.